Google Colab - refresh tokens and update them with code
I'm trying to figure out the right way to handle an OAuth flow when using Google Colab. Manually I added several variables to 'Secrets' tab and I'm fetching them with userdata module as suggested in a sample code. It works fine.
When the GET request gets a 401 code, I want to refresh the token and run the code again. However, I can't find a way to update tokens saved in 'Secrets'. I can save them as environment variables (os.environ['token'] = new_token) but the next time I run the script, it will fetch the outdated token from 'Secrets' again (token = userdata.get('token')). Here's a sample code:
from google.colab import userdata

def refresh_token():
  response = requests.post(url, data)
  tokens = response.json()
  new_token = tokens['token']
  os.environ['token'] = new_token

token = userdata.get('token')
response = requests.get(url, headers, params)
if response.status_code == 401:
  refresh_token()

Is there a way to update the 'secrets' programmatically? Or should I rely on env variables right from the start, as in:

fetch token from userdata only to save it right away as env variable
use only env variables going forward (fetch them, override them, etc)


Unfortunately, there is no API to update your secrets in Google Colab programmatically. Your provided solution which is to exclusively use environment variables for the token is the only way you can refresh and have access to the token programmatically
